# WinJS AppBarCommand Icon size

Tags: winjs

Is there a way to increase the appbar command default icons size in a WinJS application?

I've tried to search for app-bar command icon size but most of the results are around custom fonts, which is not what I want to do at this point?

Applying `class="win-x-large"` to a command does not work either.

Comment: Silly me, it's icon fonts, thus font-size can be applied. :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.win-appbar .win-commandimage
{
     font-size: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes I realised it was being silly for asking such a trivial question :$